# Drop auto generated constraint name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an auto-generated primary key constriant. The key is actually wrong. It should be against two columns and currently it is against one. I need to run this script on multiple databases and so the constraint name may be different for each database. I need to get the constraint name and then drop it and then create the new primary key.

here is the script I have so far

```
DECLARE
con_name VARCHAR(255);

BEGIN

select constraint_name into con_name from all_constraints where table_name = 'MY_TABLE' and constraint_type = 'P';

EXECUTE immediate 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE drop constraint con_name';

EXECUTE immediate 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT MT_PK PRIMARY KEY (REV, ID)';

COMMIT;
/
EXIT;
```

However I have a problem in that I think it is trying to drop con_name rather than the value within that variable.

```
Error on script: Error number: -2443, Error Message: ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint
```

Can anyone help? I basically need to drop the pk in this table. Is there any other way or is my approach the right sort of way.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `con_name` variable is out of scope within the DDL statement you're executing; you're trying to drop a constraint called `con_name`, not one named with the value that holds - as you suspected. You can't use a bind variable here so you'll need to concatenate the name:

```
DECLARE
  con_name all_constraints.constraint_name%type;
BEGIN
  select constraint_name into con_name
  from all_constraints
  where table_name = 'MY_TABLE' and constraint_type = 'P';

  EXECUTE immediate 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE drop constraint ' || con_name;

  EXECUTE immediate 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT MT_PK PRIMARY KEY (REV, ID)';
END;
/
```

As Nicholas Krasnov pointed out in a comment, you don't need to do this at all; you can [drop the primary key without specifying its name](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2133199) (also shown in the [syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2104014)) without using dynamic SQL or a PL/SQL block:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT MT_PK PRIMARY KEY (REV, ID);
```

Hopefully you don't already have any tables with foreign key constraints against this PK.

Comment: thanks - the 'DROP PRIMARY KEY' was what I did. A lot less code which is always good :)